# Not receiving push notification from iOS to android using Quickblox SDK

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, quickblox

I have used Quickblox iOS SDK for chat implementation. I am facing problem with push notification from iOS device to android device.
By default it should send push to opponent user whenever a message is sent.It does not send push from iOS to Android, however it works fine from iOS to iOS.
We have tried following code for sending universal push notification.

```
NSDictionary *payload = @{
                                          @"message" : @"Test Message",
                                          @"ios_sound" : @"mysound.wav",
                                          @"user_id" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj],
                                          @"thread_id" : @"10"
                                          };
                NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:payload options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
                NSString *messageTosend = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                QBMEvent *event = [QBMEvent event];
                event.notificationType = QBMNotificationTypePush;
                event.usersIDs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];//obj is receiver's ID
                event.type = QBMEventTypeOneShot;
                event.message = messageTosend;


                [QBRequest createEvent:event successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray<QBMEvent *> *events) {

                    // Successful response with event
                } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

                    // Handle error
                }];
```

for the above code i am getting status code as 201 but no notification at android device side.

another code i tried is following:

```
[QBRequest sendPushWithText:message toUsers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj] successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, NSArray<QBMEvent *> * _Nullable events) {


                } errorBlock:^(QBError * _Nonnull error) {


                }];
```

NOTE: in the above code "obj"is receiver's ID.

any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @hpp have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using starter(Free) Plan of Quickblox. I am also not getting proper notification in my iOS chat. When i contacted to quickblox, They called me to upgrade myPlan for Support. I upgade myPlan to pro and working fine without any changes in Code.

Comment: hey i am still facing same issue, can you please confirm this issue is belong to free or starter plan?